# d3.csv(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

> d3.csv(...).then is not a function

**app.js**

```
// Select body, append SVG area to it, and set the dimensions
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", svgHeight)
  .attr("width", svgWidth);

// Append a group to the SVG area and shift ('translate') it to the right and to the bottom
var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", `translate(${chartMargin.left}, ${chartMargin.top})`);


// Load data from hours-of-tv-watched.csv
d3.csv("hours-of-tv-watched.csv").then(function(tvData) {

console.log(tvData);

// Cast the hours value to a number for each piece of tvData
tvData.forEach(function(d) {
d.hours = +d.hours;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>Hours of TV Watched Each Month</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSV:**

```
name,hours
Han,33
Christian,12
Lisa,41
Jacob,16
Nick,59
Ahmed,38
Peleke,21
Matt,25
```

I am using is using `app.js`, showing error on:

> d3.csv(...).then is not a function

I am using the latest D3 version. I have tried using different format of:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
```

but did not work.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, I have tried searching for other answers and the one you showed me did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
and I am wondering if it's because you and I used an obsolete version of d3.js that won't allow us to use .then
I noticed that my code below worked with d3 v5 bot not previous version.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
    d.log_tot_moy = (d.log_tot_moy == "") ? 0 : +d.log_tot_moy;
    return d;

})
.then(function(data1) {
    cities = data1;
    cities.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a.log_tot_moy > b.log_tot_moy) ? -1 : ((b.log_tot_moy > a.log_tot_moy) ? 1 : 0);

    });


})
citiesOverlay.addTo(map);
```

So i have juste change the code as showing avoid .then :

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
cities = data;
cities.sort(function(a, b) {
    var p = parseInt(a.log_tot_moy);
    var q = parseInt(b.log_tot_moy);
    return (p > q) ? -1 : ((q > p) ? 1 : 0);
});
citiesOverlay.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score -2):

after figuring out on the connection to csv file, here are the step by step solutions.

For D3 v5,
-we are encouraged to use the command prompt cmd C:"enter the file path where html is stored" then enter http-server. Then go to google chrome and enter 127.0.0.1:8080 where the html will be opened.

-The easiest is to install http-server globally using node's package manager:
npm install -g http-server at command prompt.

-Error of favicon may occurred and just download the icons and save at the same folder at the html files.